# Deleting last line of a file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to delete last line of a file on a particular condition. I used sed and cut but they work only on the output stream but I want to do this in the file. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
sed -ie '$d' filename.txt
```

The `i` option tells `sed` to edit the file in place.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a variant on another answer and suggest a simple use of ed:

```
ed tmp.tmp << EOC
$
d
w
q
EOC
```

Otherwise you can use sed/cut to a temporary file and `mv` to overwrite the starting file.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
cat * > out
```

Where you could remove 'cat *' with whatever you're doing, and the out is the result of that command.

I can take a more thorough look if you provide more information on what you're trying to do.